# iOS: Use of undeclared identifier error in simple calculator

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors

I am getting this compiler error " use of undeclared identifier " just like the title says. I am trying to write to a "result" a "operationPerformed" which is basically some maths equations . I am new to Xcode so don't punish me:). Appreciate your time!

code edited accordingly

```
@interface CalculatorViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalculatorViewController
-(void)setOperand:(double)aDouble
{
    operand = aDouble;
}

-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sqrt"])
    {
        operand = sqrt(operand);
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+/-"] && operand !=0)
    {
        operand = -1 * operand;
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"1/x"] && operand !=0)
    {
        operand = 1.0 / operand;
    }

    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"sin"])
    {
        operand = sin(operand);
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"cos"])
    {
        operand = cos(operand);
    }
    else if ([operation isEqualToString:@"tan"])
    {
        operand = tan(operand);
    }
    else
    {
        [self performWaitingOperation];
        waitingOperation = operation;
        waitingOperand = operand;
    }
    return operand;
}

-(void)performWaitingOperation
{
    if ([@"+" isEqual:waitingOperation] )
    {
        operand = waitingOperand + operand;
    }
    else if ([@"*" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand * operand;
    }
    else if ([@"-" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        operand = waitingOperand - operand;
    }
    else if ([@"/" isEqual:waitingOperation])
    {
        if(operand)
        {
            operand = waitingOperand / operand;
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)operationPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber)
    {
        setOperand:[[display text] doubleValue];
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = NO;
        decimalAlreadyEnteredInDisplay = NO;
    }
    NSString * operation = [[sender titleLabel] text];
    double result = [self operformOperation:operation];
    [display setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result]];
}
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* error message.  In this case, it tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: OK I explain one ***last*** time: it's not Xcode that errors, it's the compiler, and nevermind how many times people have abused and will abuse that poor "xcode" tag, it will stay what it is, an IDE, and it won't magically become a compiler.

Comment: Knowing the exact message, and what line it flagged, would help immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
double result = performOperation:operation;
```

is invalid syntax.  Maybe you wanted:

```
double result = [self performOperation:operation];
```

Without more context it's hard to say.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it.  Or at least one of them.

Comment: i have updated code with your answer got another error in this case

Comment: You have another one that's similar: `setOperand:[[display text] doubleValue];`  I think you should get a beginner book.

Comment: i will although i am temporary in obj-c (ps. any recommendations? ). But more to the point how can i solve this issue? so i can compile the code successfully and do calculations?

Comment: What?  The second problem has exactly the same solution as the first one did.  Why don't you fix it the same way?  We're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: Sorry got lost completely. 1st. i asked if you can recommend any beginner book in obj-c. 2nd. I have noticed that i have the same issues twice. 3rd your solution worked, i have also noticed that i accidentally add few characters in places where they shouldn't be so i kept on getting another error.... currently all now seems to work ;)